# Pygame dialog system

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a simple dialog system in pygame. I have a simple dialog class.

```py
class Dialog:
    def __init__(self, npc, player):
        self.player = player
        self.npc = npc
        self.step = 0
        self.text_counter = 0
        self.text = ["Hi ",
                     "Hello",
                     "are you boss or something!?!",
                     "What!"]
        
    def update(self, key):

        if step and self.player.colliderect(self.npc):# if pressed key and if player hits npc
            self.step += 1 # skip to next text
        if self.step > len(self.text)-1:
            self.step = 0

    def draw(self, screen):
        
        draw_text(
                screen,
                self.text[self.step],
                50,
                (255, 0, 0),
                50,
                50
            )`

    merchant = Dialog(merchant,player)#call dialog class

    while True:
        merchant.update(space_key)
        merchant.draw(screen)
```

but it shows the first text without hovering over the character, I know what the problem is but I couldn't find a way to fix it,I am facing this issue because self.step is 0 automatically,do you have any ideas to solve this?

Comment: make `self.step = None` initially and do a `if self.step is not None:` and under that statement put the `draw_text` method

Comment: Matis If I set the "variable to none", I cannot increase it later.

Comment: basically have some flag that is set true when player enters the box and is set false when player leaves, then based on that flag call `draw_text`

Comment: a turn-based conversation character won't move while talking

Comment: that doesn't matter, at some point the player will enter the box and press the key and then you want to display text so set some flag to True, when the convo ends and player leaves the box set that flag to False to hide text

Comment: I want the text to appear on the screen line by line, but the way I have chosen for this does not make much sense. When the character enters the box and presses the required key, it starts speaking logically from the second text.
To be honest, this is where I'm stuck, and yet the solution you suggested isn't very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```py
import pygame


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

box = pygame.Rect(300, 200, 100, 100)
player = pygame.Rect(50, 50, 30, 30)

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 50)
texts = ['Hi', 'Hello', 'Who are ye?', 'Someone']
text_renders = [font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 255)) for text in texts]
index = -1
space_released = True

while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player.x -= 3
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        player.x += 3
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        player.y += 3
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        player.y -= 3

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), box, width=2)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), player)

    if player.colliderect(box):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and space_released:
            space_released = False
            index = (index + 1) if (index + 1) != len(text_renders) else 0
        elif not keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            space_released = True
    else:
        index = -1

    if index != -1:
        screen.blit(text_renders[index], (0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

You can initially set index to `-1` and if the index is at that position don't display text, then when you increase the index it will start at `0`, also you need to reset it  when you leave the box so that next time it starts from the beginning (if that is what you need)